# Java URLDecoder decode Percentage Symbol as error

Tags: java, urldecode

I need to allow user to input various special characters, so i use the java URLDeacoder.decode() method, i tested using println. There is no problem with other special character except this Percentage symbol, it has error during execute. Why is that? I understand that % is being used for URL encoding, is this the reason?

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern

```
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode("%", "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Percent is the beginning of an encoded value, you need the value too. For example, `%20` is a space.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah i noticed that, but is there any workaround that i can allow user to input %?

Comment: Define "special characters". Note that `URLDecoder` is meant to decode `application/x-www-form-urlencoded̀` data, which may not be what you want.

Comment: @fge those non-alphanumeric characters that can be found on a keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Despite their names, `URLEncoder/Decoder` are for encoding POST arguments, not URLs. See @fge's remarks below.

The way to encode a URL is with the URL and URI classes.

I'm curious as to how you acquired an undecoded URL in the first place.

Comment: actually, im not using it to decode URL, i used it to decode user input from text field, because if user input these characters !@#$%^&*(), it will store as undecoded value like %26, etc in database

Comment: Then you're completely back to front. The process you are looking for is *encoding,* not decoding.

Comment: no, what i mean is, when user input %, then i want it to be stored as % in database, but instead, it is storing as %26 in database, which is what i dont want.

Comment: Then there must some other process happening between the text field and the database that you haven't told us about. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: "URLEncoder/Decoder are for encoding URL arguments" <-- that's wrong. Those classes are meant to encode `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, which is not quite the same thing.

Comment: @fge URL arguments are encoded the same way as POST form arguments, no?

Comment: No, they are not. If by "arguments" you mean "query string" then no; main difference: the space ("%20" in a URL but "+" in form data). For more details, refer to RFC 3986. Also google for URI templates (this is an RFC; I have an implementation of it)

Comment: @fge So `URLEncoder.Decoder` have nothing to do with URLs at all!

Answer (score 0):

% marks the beginning of the encoded character. It should be followed by some HEXA decimal number. Else, it will throw IllegalArgumentsException and its working as per expected since you didn't specify the hexa decimal after %. Refer http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp for more details. If you were expected the output as '%', you would have to do

```
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode("%25", "UTF-8"));
```